# Python string split join 4

Tags: python, string, list, join

```
import re
string = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"


def order(sentence):
    res = ''
    count = 1
    list = sentence.split()
    for i in list:
        for i in list:
            a = re.findall('\d+', i)
            if a == [str(count)]:
                res += " ".join(i)
                count += 1
    print(res)

order(string)
```

Above there is a code which I have problem with. Output which I should get is:

```
"Thi1s is2 3a T4est"
```

Instead I'm getting the correct order but with spaces in the wrong places:

```
"T h i 1 si s 23 aT 4 e s t"
```

Any idea how to make it work with this code concept?

Comment: Why are you using `" ".join(i)` then? You joined all the characters of a single word with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You are joining the characters of each word:

```
>>> " ".join('Thi1s')
'T h i 1 s'
```

You want to collect your words into a list and join *that* instead:

```
def order(sentence):
    number_words = []
    count = 1
    words = sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        for word in words:
            matches = re.findall('\d+', word)
            if matches == [str(count)]:
                number_words.append(word)
                count += 1
    result = ' '.join(number_words)
    print(result)
```

I used more verbose and clear variable names. I also removed the `list` variable; don't use `list` as a variable name if you can avoid it, as that masks the built-in `list` name.

What you implemented comes down to a O(N^2) (quadratic time) sort. You could instead use the built-in `sort()` function to bring this to O(NlogN); you'd extract the digit and sort on its integer value:

```
def order(sentence):
    digit = re.compile(r'\d+')
    return ' '.join(
        sorted(sentence.split(), 
               key=lambda w: int(digit.search(w).group())))
```

This differs a little from your version in that it'll only look at the first (consecutive) digits, it doesn't care about the numbers being sequential, and will break for words without digits. It also uses a `return` to give the result to the caller rather than print. Just use `print(order(string))` to print the return value.

If you assume the words are numbered consecutively starting at 1, then you can sort them in O(N) time even:

```
def order(sentence):
    digit = re.compile(r'\d+')
    words = sentence.split()
    result = [None] * len(words)
    for word in words:
        index = int(digit.search(word).group())
        result[index - 1] = word
    return ' '.join(result)
```

This works by creating a list of the same length, then using the digits from each word to put the word into the correct index (minus 1, as Python lists start at 0, not 1).

Comment: If you want better complexity, you could also easily make it O(N) :-)

Comment: Intuitively I would not instantiate `results` like that, I'd use a list comp. I'm away from a PC for a while so before I forget, is there a reason you did it with `result = [None] * len(words)` if we imagine that the list is huge?

Comment: Good use of lambda. +1

Comment: @roganjosh: a list comprehension would be slower for this; as long as the *contents* of the list you multiply are immutable or you *want* the resulting list to reference the same objects, use multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bug is simply in the misuse of join(). You want to concatenate the current sorted string. `i` is simply a token, hence simply add it to the end of the string. Code untested.

```
import re
string = "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"


def order(sentence):
    res = ''
    count = 1
    list = sentence.split()
    for i in list:
        for i in list:
            a = re.findall('\d+', i)
            if a == [str(count)]:
                res = res + " " + i # your bug here
                count += 1
    print(res)

order(string)
```

Comment: Thanks man it's working now, it's was my misconception of how .join work it seems.

Comment: This leaves a space a the start.

Comment: @Aaken00: I don't think you misunderstand how join works, you just used it on the wrong sequence.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Nice spot. Yes, maybe calling `res = res[1:]` will do? Can't remember the syntax.

Comment: @Tuan333: well, the canonical method is to make `res` a list, use `res.append(i)`, then use `' '.join(res)` at the end.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes. Or your lambda function approach would be my preferred way too. I answered OP's question without any testing, so did not dare to venture near lambda or any heavy modification.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Yea i mean got the general idea but couldn't figure out why it's not working in this case nevertheless i think i know now, thanks for the help/explanation